# Graphql Apollo chaining lazy queries in onCompleted gives weird behaviour

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo

I have a component with these functions and hooks. In the useffect everything happens as expected, but when I use the getMenuItem() seperately in another function the onCompleted callback from useMenuTreeLazyQuery gets invoked even though the useEffect does not run (is the only place menuTree() is used). What is happening here? does both onCompleted from both hooks gets invoked when one of them is activated?

possible issue (just thinking):

1. they both return a list of MenuItems, so when the apollo cache gets populated with the first query the second querys onCompleted gets invoked because it detected changes?
2. both queries return an array of MenuItem, and the cache cant differentiate between them.
3. the datafetch from useMenuTreeLazyQuery is allmost identical to the useGetMenuItemLazyQuery query. And for some reason triggers useMenuTreeLazyQuery because its too similar and theres only an array of menuitems, so theres no identifier
4. having another query inside oncompleted on another queries is not good

my code:

```
  const populateMenu = (data?: MenuTree | MenuItemList | null) => {
    const getVisibleMenu = data?.filter((menu) => menu?.visible) || [];
    setMenuContent(getVisibleMenu);
  };
  const [getMenuItem, { error: menuItemError }] = useGetMenuItemLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log('ITEM complete');
      if (menuItemError) {
        setError(generalMenuErrorText);
        return null;
      }

      populateMenu(data.menuItem);
    },
  });
  const [menuTree, { error: menuTreeError }] = useMenuTreeLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log('TREE complete');
      if (menuTreeError) {
        setError(generalMenuErrorText);
        return null;
      }
      if (menuIdInit) {
        getMenuItem({
          variables: {
            query: Number(menuIdInit),
          },
        });
      } else {
        populateMenu(data.menuTree);
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      menuTree({
        variables: {
          relativeUrl,
        },
      });
    }
  }, [menuTree, open, relativeUrl]);
```